Unexpected behavior of do
I'm getting this expected output
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper do q(./dotest.pl)'
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
        ];

while dotest.pl is
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x=1;
if ($x) {
  my $ret = [
    # map { my %h = (x => $_); \%h }
    1..4
  ];
}

sub foo { 1 }

However, when I uncomment the map transformation, the oneliner doesn't output anything.
Is it a bug? perl is 5.34.0

If I remove the last "sub foo" statement, it does work. So there is some interaction there. Maybe a race condition between compiler and precompiler? 1..4 is a constant and does not need evaluation, whereas the map statement needs runtime evaluation. It also works if you explicitly return $ret last in the file, or if you remove the if-clause.

indeed, and I've managed to get into exact set of the circumstances.

You didn't check if an exception was caught by do, but it didn't.
Aside from catching exceptions, it should behave the same as the following:
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

sub f {
  my $x=1;
  if ($x) {
    my $ret = [
      map { my %h = (x => $_); \%h }
      1..4
    ];
  }

  sub foo { 1 }
}

print Dumper f();

Like you, I get nothing from the do version, but the above dumps an AoH.
So they don't behave the same. The do version doesn't return the result of the last expression evaluated (the assignment) as it should. So yeah, it's a bug. And it's still present in 5.40.
It's some kind of context issue. Calling do in scalar context works.
What you posted really pushes the limit of acceptable code, though :)

do BLOCK has the same problem.
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper do {
  my $x=1;
  if ($x) {
    my $ret = [
      map { my %h = (x => $_); \%h }
      1..4
    ];
  }

  sub foo { 1 }
};

And with do BLOCK, we can have a look at the opcodes.
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec do.pl
[...]
x      <1> padsv_store[$ret:1274,1275] vKS/LVINTRO
[...]

See that v? It's being evaluated in void context. The subroutine version above evaluates it in scalar context.
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec,f sub.pl
main::f:
[...]
s      <1> padsv_store[$ret:1274,1275] sKS/LVINTRO
[...]


Interestingly, some transformations like map { { x => $_ } } don't trigger the bug.

Didn't we have a question recently about the { ... } block functions and their limitations?

Appended to my answer.
